# The element modifiers classList.add and classList.remove not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of items (`ul, li`) with a class that sets a border left and bold highlight when you click the item.

When you click on a different item in the list I want to reset the style to the original item so that it goes back to normal, and then set a new style on the active one just clicked.

What is strange is that the DOM inspection shows that previous clicked items still have the changed class, but when I output to the console it says it doesn't.

```
 function myFunctionTest(id_word) {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("process-itemz");
         for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
         items[i].classList.remove("test123");
}

var element = document.getElementById(id_word);
  element.classList.add("test123");

}
```

And a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y5kwmu6j/

Comment: `add` is a method. You need to invoke it as `element.classList.add("test123")`

Comment: sorry, adjusted, but same issue any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here in the end? Some sort of poor man’s checkbox/radio button replacement …? If this is intended to be some sort of control element for the user to interact with and select elements, then this should use actual checkboxes/radio buttons to begin with, everything else is rather bad for usability.

Comment: Its just a list of span items that when you click one will change the way it looks to show it is highlighted.

Comment: I thing it may not get the actual index .when remove class use for loop .But when add you did not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

`element.classList.add = "test123";` should be `element.classList.add("test123");`

You should change the order of the css rules so that the `.test123` rules are after the `.process-itemz` rules. They're the same level of specificity, so the later ones will win.

Comment: Double check that your js code is being injected properly. In your fiddle i had to change the load type to "end of <body>" to ensure that it was being injected. Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rnv3thqp/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned there were a few syntax changes necessary, plus I reformatted your loop.

The attached code snippet works - please ensure your JavaScript is either linked in your HTML file, or it's embedded between script tags.

```js
function myFunctionTest(id_word) {
  alert(1);
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("process-itemz");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove("test123");
  }

  var element = document.getElementById(id_word);
  element.classList.add("test123");

}
```

```css
.default {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.test123 {
  border-left: 1rem solid rgba(167, 194, 15, 0.623);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.process-itemz {
  border-left: 1rem solid rgba(167, 194, 15, 0);
  font-weight: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="default">
  <ul id="foo">
    <li>

      <span onclick="myFunctionTest(this.id)" id="testa123" class="process-itemz">&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;
                   Excavation Hire
                  </span>
    </li>
    <li>


      <span onclick="myFunctionTest(this.id)" id="testb123" class="process-itemz">&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace; Rubbish Removal</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As another answer suggested, you'll want to change the order of your css selectors. Since they have the same priority the `.process-items` selector will override everything in `.test123`.

Another suggestion is to actually combine the class selectors like so:

`.process-itemz.test123`

In this case the order won't matter in the css since this selector will always be more specific.

[See "How is specificity calculated?" on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Your mileage may vary depending on your use case though.

```js
function myFunctionTest(id_word) {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("process-itemz");
  for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    items[i].classList.remove("test123");
  }

  var element = document.getElementById(id_word);
  element.classList.add("test123");
}
```

```css
.default {
  font-weight: 200;
}

.process-itemz {
  border-left: 1rem solid rgba(167, 194, 15, 0);
  font-weight: inherit;
}

.process-itemz.test123 {
  border-left: 1rem solid rgba(167, 194, 15, 0.623);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="default">
  <ul id="foo">
    <li>

      <span onclick="myFunctionTest(this.id);" id="testa123" class="process-itemz">&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;
                   Excavation Hire
                  </span>
    </li>
    <li>


      <span onclick="myFunctionTest(this.id);" id="testb123" class="process-itemz">&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace;&ThickSpace; Rubbish Removal</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```